# Reconnecting with lost contacts

Tags: networking

Assuming someone had a nice network of contacts but lost them because of his own ignorance (too busy with work to keep in touch), what is a good strategy to reconnect with them?

I don't think the answer is as simple as calling them up and asking for a meet over coffee since the person under consideration has politely refused many such requests owing to his busy schedule.

Comment: Not sure I'd consider this a workplace issue. Do they work with you any more? Do you need to work with them professionally?

Comment: I do need to correspond every once in a while (although that time hasn't come yet but I predict it will come soon).

Comment: How you tried to connec with them on LinkedIn?

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner I don't use it.

Comment: Could also be considered a duplicate of [Staying in touch with people you meet at conferences](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/2314/staying-in-touch-with-people-you-meet-at-conferences)

Comment: I think this question can be reopened if someone (preferably OP) edits it to add explanation why there is a need to reconnect and how that need relates to workplace setting. As an example, I can imagine one willing to reconnect intending to hire past colleagues into current company / team, or to ask their advice about some professional matters etc